# Loop-carried class dependence

Tags: c++, class

Here are my classes:

```
class Base {
public:
    template <typename T>
    static struct M {
        T* open(string name, Dir *parent = NULL) {
            if ( parent ) {
                return parent->open_child(name);
            } else {
                auto ans = new T(name);
                ans->open();
                return ans;
            }
        }
    };

    virtual void open() =0;
};

class Dir : public Base {
public:
    template <typename T>
    T* open_child(string name);

    void open();
};

class File : public Base {
public:
    void open();
};
```

Here, `Dir` class requres `Base` prototype, `Base` requres `Dir`. Forward declaration will not work: only full definitions suitable for inheritance and method call.
Assume that I want to emplace this code into 3 header files: Base.h, Dir.h and File.h.
How can I remake my code to break circular dependence?

Comment: if you rethink those header without using template but design an interface class instead it would become easier.

Comment: Simply moving the implementation code out of Base should allow you to work with forward declaration of Dir for its definition.

Comment: @heinrichj but I can't move it out since that's a template.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>

class Dir;

class Base
{
  public:
    template <typename T>
    struct M
    {
      T* open(std::string name, Dir* parent = nullptr);
    };
};

class Dir : public Base
{
  // Further definitions
};

// Implementation

template <typename T>
T* Base::M<T>::open(std::string name, Dir* parent)
{
  // Implementation goes here...
}
```

Comment: Since template prototype and implementation must be in one translation unit, seems that your solution doesn't support code separation to more than one files...

Comment: That's correct... It's not clear to me why you want the utility "open" function in Base (and in a nested template no less). If you can move it entirely outside Base there wouldn't be a problem anymore.